# Php Mail from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parsing, email

I created a simple php mail script that emails and does what it is supposed to do, but my problem is that I am not recieving the JSON info from my ajax call.

HTML form.

```
 <form>
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>

    <img src="img/grey_logo.png" alt="grey logo" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder="First Name">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Pnum" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </li>
    </ul>
     <h3>Do you have Insurance?</h3>

    <ul class="last">
        <li>
            <label>Yes</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ins_yes">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>No</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ins_no">
        </li>
    </ul>
     <h3>Your private Information is Important to us, we will never ask for sensitive information </h3>

    <input type="text" name="insur" placeholder="Your Insurance Name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

AJAX by jquery

```
function mail() {
    var first = $('input[name="Fname"]').val();
    var last = $('input[name="Lname"]').val();
    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    var yes = $('input[name="ins_yes"]').val();
    var no = $('input[name="ins_no"]').val();
    var phone = $('input[name="Pnum"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'first': first,
                'last': last,
                'email': email,
                'yes': yes,
                'no': no,
                'phone': phone
        },
        success: alert("Success")
    });
    return false;
}
$('#envelope form').submit(mail);
```

PHP simplified:

```
$first  =    $_POST['first'];
$last   =    $_POST['last'];
$email  =    $_POST['email'];
$yes    =    $_POST['yes'];
$no     =    $_POST['no'];
$phone  =    $_POST['phone'];

$to      = 'test@test.com';
$subject = 'Contact Info';
$message = 'Contact persons First Name :'.$first;
$headers = 'From: contact-omt<webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "success";
```

I have also tried decoding the json as well.

EDIT
I am getting emails, but my problem is more towards not seeing `$first` value after Contact Persons First Name:

Comment: One problem I can see, you have JS variables var last and var no when those are predefined global variables you need to rename those to something else.

Comment: Where are you calling your `mail()` function in HTML

Comment: @Cam first try to call only ajax file which is mail.php from your browser and check does emails are sending or not with static data?

Comment: @ChintanGor it is processing correctly and I am getting emails.

Comment: @RajeshLohar at the bottom in the php portion you will see mail($to, $subject etc etc).

Comment: @MitchLayzell I will change those, completely forgot those are global variables.

Comment: By ajax are you getting emails?
if yes
then your emails are going to SPAM
if yes Then you need to use php emailer phpmailer driver

Comment: echo $_POST['first']; n see if it posts any value. Dnt send e-mail. Just echo the value and check whether it displays anything.

Comment: Figured it out, I wasnt using the correct post data, I thought it was first, it was Fname.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I wouldn't send the data by creating a variable for each input I would create a function that would take all the form elements and create a JSON object and pass that with Ajax. Like I said in my comment you were using `var last` and `var no` which are predefined JS variables so you'll need to rename, but this is typically how I would submit a form with Ajax,

**HTML**

```
<form class="form" action="somehandler.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="first">
     <input type="text" name="last">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
/* 
Awesome JS function we can add to create a serialize object and pass that,
it takes the forms element name and value and makes and object.
*/
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {

    var object = {};
    $.each(this.serializeArray(), function() {

        if (object[this.name] !== undefined) {

            if (!object[this.name].push) {
                object[this.name] = [object[this.name]];
            }
            object[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } 
        else {

            object[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return object;
};


$('.form').submit(function(e)) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serializeObject();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : $(this).attr('action'),
        dataType: "json",
        data: data
    }).done(function(result) {  

        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry it ended up being my json name, Fname not first

Comment: No worries, you might want to think about using the function above though that way you can get the data from any form no matter how many or what input, select or textareas there are.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to include dataType : 'json' in your $.ajax method. and in your PHP file

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
$return['message'] =  'yes, I did it';
echo json_encode($return);
  }
else{
  $return['message'] =  'Oooops, Shame';
  echo json_encode($return);
}
```

And in your $.ajax Success Call back you can alert like this

```
    success: function(r){
            alert(r.message);
        }
```

You may use PHPMailer Class for sending mails, so you dont want to worry about anything missing and all, 100% you can relay on it.